# Adding dynamic content on page such as Sitefinity or Dotnetnuke

Tags: user-controls, dotnetnuke, sitefinity, dynamic-controls, dynamic-content

How can i create dynamic content on page such as Sitefinity or Dotnetnuke?How can i manage user controls with drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With DotNetNuke often times Dynamic content is added through the use of modules.

I have an open source Article module that you can check out at https://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/